# Simulate keypress and change input value on user click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this working with Postcode Anywhere software. My postcode field is auto-populated and as a result the search function is not firing unless the user starts to delete and re-enter their postcode.

If I hit spacebar straight after the postcode, the search function works. So this is what I am trying to simulate. When the user clicks the postcode input field, a space is physically entered after the existing postcode entry.

I've tried other keypress scripts on here but they dont actually add the character to the input field.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a way to trigger the PA lookup itself through their API, rather than forcing a value change to trigger it?  Would be surprised if you couldn't invoke it directly

Comment: Apparently not. This fix was actually suggested by their Support staff. I called them first to find a solution because I thought I can't be the only one to try and do this! 

When I asked if they had a copy of a keypress script that would be compatible they suggested I google it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as this, but I needed a quicker fix so I ended up repeating my implementation across each page, rather than using one page for the search and redirecting the search from other pages.

However, in the meantime I did ask a member of PA staff and they responded with this today:

> Hi Andy,
>   It is possible, the Auto search function may help in this situation:
>
> `capturePlus.listen("options", function(options) { options.autoSearch = true; });`
>
> This should auto search on start-up.

---

I hope this helps someone.
Andy